# Terminology: "Sum over Geometries" vs. "Sum over Topologies" in Quantum Gravity

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, quantum-gravity, topology, loop-quantum-gravity

I am currently studying loop quantum gravity and related approaches like simplicial quantum gravity, spin foam models, tensor models and group field theories. In texts about this topics, one often encounters phrases like "sum over geomtries" and "sum over topologies" and since I am coming more from the mathematical side, I am a little bit confused what these terms exactly mean.

Usually these terms appear when one wants to calculate transition amplitudes between some given "boundary" spatial geometries. As far as I've understood so far, the term "sum over geometries" means that I "sum" over all possible (Lorentzian) metrics on some **fixed** space-times manifold equipped with a **fixed** topology on it. Of course, maybe one has to restrict the sum over metric satisfying certain boundary conditions, ect. But conceptionally, this is what is meant by "summing over geometries", am I right?

Secondly, in some theories, one in addition wants to "sum over topologies". Now this is the part, where I do not exactly know what people mean by this phrase. So basically the idea is to make "topology dynamical". This is also sometimes called the "3rd quantization idea" in the quantum gravity community. But what is meant by "sum over topologies"? Does this include a sum over **all** possible manifolds matching the boundary conditions (like bordisms between the two boundary manifolds describing space) or does this only mean I still work with a **fixed** manifold, but now I do not only sum over all metrics but in addition I sum over all topologies on this manifold?

Comment: The prototypical example is  two dimensions. The outer "sum over topologies" means a sum over all possible values for the genus $g$ and number of boundaries $n$. Then the inner "sum over geometries" is an integral over the $\mathcal{M}_{g, n}$ moduli space.

Comment: Okay I see, so "sum over topologies" does then really mean that I sum over all possible manifolds, right?

Comment: Yes. I'm tempted to say that the inner sum is over manifolds which are diffeomorphic to each other while the outer sum is not.